# How to do case when expression in select?

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

I tried to do a select statement with a case when expression.
I get an error

> Invalid sql statement

This is for Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT DATUM_EINDE AANPAK,
       CASE WHEN DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK IS NULL THEN DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK
       ELSE MAX(DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK)
       END AS DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK
FROM T_CJIB_CVE;
```

Comment: you would probably need group by as you are using aggregate function

Comment: Are you sure your table has a column named `DATUM_EINDE` as well as one named `DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK`? You might have missed an underscore in the first line.

Comment: check this link:  https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (And you'll get better answers, faster.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I guess that this is what you're looking for; for ID = 2, datum is null so - take the largest datum from the whole table.

```
SQL> with t_cjib_cve (id, datum_einde_aanpak) as
  2    (select 1, date '2019-06-17' from dual union all
  3     select 2, null              from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2019-01-01' from dual
  5    )
  6  select datum_einde_aanpak,
  7         case when datum_einde_aanpak is null then
  8                     (select max(datum_einde_aanpak) from t_cjib_cve)
  9              else datum_einde_aanpak
 10         end result
 11  from t_cjib_cve;

DATUM_EIND RESULT
---------- ----------
2019-06-17 2019-06-17
           2019-06-17
2019-01-01 2019-01-01

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

use max like below

```
SELECT DATUM_EINDE, AANPAK,
       max(CASE WHEN DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK IS NULL THEN DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK
       ELSE DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK END)
        AS DATUM_EINDE_AANPAK
FROM T_CJIB_CVE group by DATUM_EINDE, AANPAK
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE with sub-query for retreiving the max date

```
SELECT CASE WHEN datum_einde_aanpak IS NULL THEN null
  ELSE (SELECT MAX(datum_einde_aanpak) as max_date FROM t_cjib_cve) 
  END as datum_einde_aanpak
FROM t_cjib_cve a
```